# systemd-resolved DNS is not cleared when switching network

Tags: network-manager, dns, systemd, systemd-resolved

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 with systemd 245 and network-manager 1.22.10. When I connect to a Wi-Fi that advertise IPv4 and IPv6 DNS, it works correctly and `systemd-resolved --status` shows the IPv4 DNS under my wireless interface.

However, when I disconnect from this network, `systemd-resolved --status` shows the link-local IPv6 address of the previous DNS. This is a problem because when I connect to another network that doesn't advertise DNS (I use mDNS), any DNS requests are long because the nss waits for the IPv6 DNS to timeout.

How can I make sure the DNS are cleared when disconnecting/switching networks?

EDIT: After digging with dbus-monitor and running NetworkManager with TRACE enabled, it seems NetworkManager is explicitely setting the DNS after the disconnection:

```
dns-mgr: config:      100 default v6 3     : fe80::7645:2dff:feae:e74
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/995

It should be resolved with NetworkManager 1.40.